# Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. Using future builder and obx

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I'm using flutter and [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get), so i'm implementing `Obx` inside my code.

I have 3 files:

`questionnaire.dart`
`questionnnaire_controller.dart`
`popup.dart`

Inside the `popup.dart` I have the layout of the popup.

Inside `questionnaire.dart` I have the code that displays the content of a popup that displays a questionnaire to be answered.

Inside `questionnaire_controller.dart` i have some variables and functions that are used, like the function `getQuestionnaires()` that gets the questionnaires' data asynchronously, or the list `questionnaires`, or a variable `selectedQuestionnaire` that keeps the instance of a questionnaire that has been selected.

Inside the `popup.dart` I have to display on top of the popup dialog, the title of the questionnaire, if a questionnaire has been selected. A part of the code is the following:

```
static Future<void> showQuestionnaireInput({String title, Widget child, Widget icon}) async {
    bool mobileSize = Get.size.width <= ResponsiveSizingConfig.instance.breakpoints.desktop;
    if (mobileSize) {
      await Get.to(InputScreenWidget(child, title));
    } else {
      await showDialog(
          context: Get.context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              title: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade200, width: 2))),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          if (icon != null) icon,
                          if (icon != null) SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Text(title),
                          Obx(() {
                            if(questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaireTitle.value != '')
                              return Text(questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaireTitle.value);
                            else
                              return Container();
                          }),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    CloseButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Get.back();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              content: child,
            );
          });
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, inside the obx i'm getting the value of the selectedQuestionnaireTitle, which is a variable that exists inside `questionnnaire_controller.dart`.

Inside the `questionnaire.dart` i have a `future builder` that bring my questionnaire data, in order for the user to choose one of them via a dropdown and answer the respective questions by clicking next. A part of the code that is useful for our case is the following:

```
child: Obx(() {
              if (questionnaireController.questionnaireState.value == QuestionnaireController.QUESTIONNAIRE_CHOOSE) {
                return Container(
                  width: screenWide ? Get.size.width * 0.5 : Get.size.width * 1,
                  child: Center(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: questionnaireController.getQuestionnaires(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          questionnaireController.dialIsBuilt.value = true;
                          print(questionnaireController.dialIsBuilt.value);
                          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                            case ConnectionState.waiting:
                              questionnaireController.dialIsBuilt.value = false;
                              print(questionnaireController.dialIsBuilt.value);
                              return CircularProgressIndicator();
                            default:
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                print(questionnaireController.dialIsBuilt.value);
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'choose_questionnaire'.tr,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: TextSize.TEXT_LARGE,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        color: EnvironmentVariables.mainColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 8,
                                    ),
                                    Dropdown(
                                      questionnaires: questionnaireController.questionnaires,
                                      selectedQuestionnaire: questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaire,
                                    ),
                                    Obx(
                                      () {
                                        if (questionnaireController.buttonDisplay.value == true) {
                                          return Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                            child: defaultButton(
                                              text: 'next_question'.tr,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                questionnaireController.answerQuestionnaire();
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          return Container();
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              } else
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'choose_questionnaire'.tr,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: TextSize.TEXT_LARGE,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        color: EnvironmentVariables.mainColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    // Text("no_data".tr),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 32,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                          }
                        }),
                  ),
                );
              }
```

You can see, inside the code above, a widget named `Dropdown`. It is a stateful widget that i have created. This widget, also exists inside `questionnaire.dart`. The code for `Dropdown` is as follows.

```
class Dropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List questionnaires;
  final Questionnaire selectedQuestionnaire;

  Dropdown({
    this.questionnaires,
    this.selectedQuestionnaire,
  });

  @override
  _DropdownState createState() => _DropdownState(
        questionnaires: questionnaires,
        // dropdownValue: selectedQuestionnaire.title,
      );
}

class _DropdownState extends State<Dropdown> {
  List questionnaires;
  String dropdownValue = questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaire.title;

  _DropdownState({
    this.questionnaires,
    // this.dropdownValue,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    questionnaireController.setSelectedQuestionnaire(questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaire);
    return DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: true,
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: EnvironmentVariables.mainColor, fontSize: TextSize.TEXT_SMALL),
      underline: Container(
        height: 1.6,
        color: EnvironmentVariables.mainColor,
      ),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        widget.questionnaires.forEach((questionnaire) {
          if (questionnaire.title == newValue) {
            questionnaireController.setSelectedQuestionnaire(questionnaire);
            // questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaire = questionnaire;
          }
        });
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => setState(() {
          dropdownValue = questionnaireController.selectedQuestionnaire.title;
        }));


        //Show continue button
        questionnaireController.showButton();

        //Used in reminder
      },
      items: widget.questionnaires.map((questionnaire) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: questionnaire.title,
          child: Text(
            questionnaire.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: EnvironmentVariables.secondaryColor),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

When i run the code, and i open the popup dialog, i get the following error

> The following assertion was thrown building Dropdown(dirty, state: _DropdownState#97b88):
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>
> This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
> framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can
> be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of
> its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because
> the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
> dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might
> not visit this widget during this build phase. The widget on which
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Obx   state:
> _ObxState#d84a8 The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Dropdown   dirty   state:
> _DropdownState#97b88 The relevant error-causing widget was:    Dropdown

My question is, how do i solve this error? I know that the following function can be helpful

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // executes after build
})
```

But where should i implement the above function?

Thank you for your time

Comment: addPostFrameCallback ---> will call after the build complete its works, so initialize this addPostFrameCallback Inside initState() method to avoid exception

Comment: Exception is cause due to calling the addPostFrameCallback and calling the setState inside the method only

Comment: just as an aside, to you rissue, i'd recommend not coupling your dropdown component to your Questionaire component, and instead pass the questionare data in and receive a callback. Your dropdown componen then beceomes re-usable for other use cases or different data. And also independently testable of the questionaire functionality. As well as make it simpler and ultimately more efficient.

Answer (score 18):

If your using the Statefull widget you can initialize inside the initState

```
initState(){
 super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // executes after build
  });
}
```

Need to known:

1. addPostFrameCallback will fire after the build call finished it's work

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added this inside the _DropdownState (State class) just before the build function. It seems it's doing the job. The only thing is that when i open the popup dialog, the error displays for an instant (just for some milliseconds) and then the widget displays. How can we fix this?

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the image.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (not related to `Get` package) I was seeing the error while using `StreamBuilder`, I was modifying the state based on data received from the stream. What I needed to do is to delay it from build process with `Future.delayed`:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
  setState(() {
    // Update app state
  });
});
```

It might introduce infinite loop if state keeps updating without some kind of `if` check.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused if you are calling controller.update() on the widget constructor. Assuming you're using GetBuilder.

Example

```
class IconPickerPage extends GetView<HomeController> {

IconPickerPage (){
   controller.update(); //this is the cause.
}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  GetBuilder<HomeController>(
     builder: (controller)
     {
      return SizedBox();
     }
     );
  }
}
```